# An argument for the parameter named 'subtitle' has already been specified. Try removing one of the named arguments. or edit one of the names

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I want to add text to ListView. But when I add another subtitle it doesn't run and I change to new arguments it doesn't run.

```
 return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: problemlist.length,
                        itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                          problemModel problem = problemlist[index];
                          return Card(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: Text(
                                problem.name_surname,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 19),
                              ),
                              subtitle: Text(
                                problem.address,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17),
                              ),
                              trailing: Text(
                                problem.status,
                               style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                             ),
                              subtitle: Text(
                                problem.address,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }));
```

ERROR
The argument for the named parameter 'subtitle' was already specified.
Try removing one of the named arguments, or correcting one of the names to reference a different named parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ListTile` you're defining `subtitle` twice

```dart
ListTile(
  title: ...,
  subtitle: ...,
  trailing: ...,
  subtitle: ...,
)
```

It should be:

```dart
ListTile(
  title: ...,
  subtitle: ...,
  trailing: ...,
)
```